# How to update Firestore data on another Flutter page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that adds data to the database. I need to update this data on another page. Tell me what code you need to write to update this data only on another page.

```
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final db = Firestore.instance;

   void createData() async {
            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              _formKey.currentState.save();
              DocumentReference ref = await db.collection('users').add({'email': '$_email', 'name': 'UserName', 'userPhotoURL': 'url'});
              setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
              print(ref.documentID);
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if your question is, how to update ui when there is a new data comes in, you can get your data with `StreamBuilder` widget. Which will update the ui if new data comes up.

[StreamBuilder class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshots(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else { 
          <DocumentSnapshot> items = snapshot.data.documents;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${ds["url"]}'),
              );
            }
          );
        } 
   }
 )
```

Comment: I have a form in which I write down the mail, the name and I need this data to be updated in the database. The code in which I add data to the database is above.

Comment: How to make the data that is written in the TextFormField update the data that has already been recorded